# Is there any way to find out the returned object is a proxy object or a real object?

Tags: java

I am doing some experiments on spring @configuration annotation and i found that it need CGLIB as it's dependent library.As we know CGLIB is used to generate the code at run time(generating proxy object at run time),I need to under stand if the bean returned by the following code block is a proxy object or real object

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
Person person=(Person)context.getBean("person");
```

AppConfig is my java based configuration class.

Answer (score -1):

```
java.​lang.​reflect.Proxy.isProxyClass( person.getClass() ) || org.​springframework.​util.ClassUtils.isCglibProxyClass( person.getClass() )
```

Comment: You should include some explanation of your answer.